# GET vs POST API calls and cache issues

Tags: api, rest, post, caching, get

I know that GET is used to retrieve data from the server without modifying anything. Whereas POST is used to add data. I won't get into PUT/PATCH, and assume that POST is always used to update and replace data.

The theory is nice, but in practice I have encountered many situations where my GET calls need to be replaced with POST calls. This is because the response often gets incorrectly cached. Where I work there are proxy servers for security, caching, load balancing, etc., and often times the response for GET calls is directly cached to speed up the call, whereas POST calls never get fully cached.

So for my question, if I have an API call /api/get_orders/month. Theoretically, this should be a GET call, however, the number of orders might update any second. So if I call this API at any moment it may return for example 1000, and calling it just two seconds later should return 1001. However, because of the cache, and although adding a version flag such as ?v=<date_as_int> should ensure that the updated value is returned, there seems to be some caches in the proxy servers that might ignore this.

Basically, I don't feel safe enough using GET unless I know for certain that the data will not be modified or if I know for a fact that the response is always the updated data.

So, would you recommend using POST/GET in the case of retrieving daily/monthly number of orders. And if GET, with all the different and complex layers and server set-ups, how can one be certain that the data is always updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing multiple `GET` request and *something* is caching the data in between, you have no idea what it is or how to change it's behavior then `POST` is a valid workaround.

In any normal situation you would take the time what sits in between your browser and your server, and if there's something that's behaving in a way that doesn't make sense, I would try to investigate and fix that.

So you work at a place where some of that infrastructure exists. Maybe talk to the people that maintain it? But if that's not an option and you just want to find the 'ignore every convention and make my request work'-workaround, then you can use `POST`.

Comment: Hello Evert. I know that we use CloudFlare and that there is a server caching requests. I don't know exactly what the caching "configurations" are, however, I do know this is intentional because it greatly speeds up many API calls.
But, my question is not strictly related to our application. Rather, if we have this cache I imagine many other applications may have similar solutions set up. So my question is more generically if this is something that others have faced and if using POST calls to avoid caching is an accepted solution or if there is a better way to go about it.

Comment: @FabianSvensson I'll rephrase. `GET` does not cache by default. If something causes it to cache anyway, you _should_ fix that and don't use `POST` just to circumvent this.